# LibGDX Listener in Actor in Stage doesn't work

Tags: events, input, libgdx, listener, stage

The input listener doesn't fire in the Actor even if the Actor was already added to the stage and the input processor was already set to the stage. What could be the problem here?
Inside GameScreen (extends Screen) class:

```java
public GameScreen(Game game) {
   this.game = game;
   stage = new Stage(800, 480, true);
   number = new Number();
   stage.addActor(number);
}

public void show() {
   Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

public void render(float delta) {
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   stage.act(delta);
   stage.draw();
}
```

Constructor of Number:

```java
public Number() {
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("touch down");
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("touch up");
            }

            public boolean mouseMoved(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                System.out.println("mouse moved");
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are pressing the actor? Where is your code which gives the actor a size for example? can you show it being rendered using a Table in your Stage?

Comment: OH. Such a careless mistake, I have not set the size and position of the actor. Thanks.

Comment: So this is solved or not?